# nav links get separated each in a new row with css-grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to get the three links together above each other and center them in the middle of the page. (Like on the screenshot).

I have tried things like grid-row: 1; but doesn't seem to work. Seems like they get separated on a new row, but there is only 1 row with the full height of the page.

This is a pic of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

this is a picture of the problem:
[image]

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4a6163;
  font-family: "Asap";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 0.15fr 0.5fr (1fr)[1];
      grid-template-columns: 0.15fr 0.5fr repeat(1, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav_section {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.left_column {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 3;
}

.right_colomn {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 4;
}

.left_column > h1 {
  font-family: "Asap";
  color: #f9faf4;
  font-size: 13.75rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 15.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-writing-mode: tb-rl;
      -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
          writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
          transform: rotate(-180deg);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.main_bio {
  color: #f2c4ce;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
      -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
          flex-direction: column-reverse;
  padding: 6rem;
}

.nav_section {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: blue 4px solid;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

.main_nav {
  display: block;
}

.main_nav > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2c4ce;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f2c4ce;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.main_nav > a {
  color: #f2c4ce;
}

.social_nav > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2c4ce;
}
```

```
<main>
        <div class="main_grid">
            <div class="nav_section">
                <nav class="main_nav" aria-label="main_navigation">
                        <a href="#">home</a>
                        <a href="#">work</a>
                        <a href="#">contact</a>    
                </nav>

                <nav class="social_nav" aria-label="social_navigation">
                    <a href="#">github</a>
                    <a href="#">linkedin</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="left_column">
                <h1 class="main_title">Hello,<br> I'm Jack</h1>
            </div>
           <div class="right_colomn">
              <p class="main_bio">A 20 YEAR OLD FROM A SMALL TOWN NEAR AMSTERDAM. CURRENTLY STUDYING COMPUTER SCIENCE IN LEIDEN.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried adding this css, and it seems to work :)

## first put in the end this

```css
.main_nav,
.social_nav {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
```

##### delete this

and deleting in your `.main_nav>a` selector this:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

### or change to this

and in the end, it will be:

```css
.main_nav>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2c4ce;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    align-items: center;
}
```

## Here The Runnable Code on JFFIDLE :)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4a6163;
    font-family: "Asap";
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.15fr 0.5fr repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.nav_section {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

.left_column {
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 3;
}

.right_colomn {
    -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 4;
}

.left_column>h1 {
    font-family: "Asap";
    color: #f9faf4;
    font-size: 13.75rem;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15.75rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 3rem;
}

.main_bio {
    color: #f2c4ce;
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    padding: 6rem;
}

.nav_section {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    border: blue 4px solid;
    grid-row: 1;
    display: grid;
}

.main_nav {
    display: block;
}

.main_nav>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2c4ce;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f2c4ce;
}

.main_nav>a {
    color: #f2c4ce;
}

.social_nav>a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2c4ce;
}

.main_nav,
.social_nav {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.main_nav>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f2c4ce;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="main_grid">
            <div class="nav_section">
                <nav class="main_nav" aria-label="main_navigation">
                    <a href="#">home</a>
                    <a href="#">work</a>
                    <a href="#">contact</a>
                </nav>

                <nav class="social_nav" aria-label="social_navigation">
                    <a href="#">github</a>
                    <a href="#">linkedin</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="left_column">
                <h1 class="main_title">Hello,<br> I'm Jack</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="right_colomn">
                <p class="main_bio">A 20 YEAR OLD FROM A SMALL TOWN NEAR AMSTERDAM. CURRENTLY STUDYING COMPUTER SCIENCE IN LEIDEN.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

> is this help you, please upvote this to help more people !